# jquery change event trigger

Tags: jquery, input, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem in need of help of JQuery. 
JQuery give my input to increase the use of case change.
the code:

```
#(".inp").bind("change",function (){
  if(isNaN(this.value)){
    this.value = 0;
  }
}
```

When I first time to enter characters, change case happened, input values changed to 0 But when I enter the **same** character a second time, change does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

From [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#fn):

> The change event fires when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus.

So, it it fired only once. And that's why you have the behaviour you got. I would use [the KeyDown event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keydown#fn), because

> The keydown event fires when a key on the keyboard is pressed.

To use this event you have to do something like this:

```
$('.inp').keydown(function(event){
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    // ...
    // different keys do different things
    // Different browsers provide different codes
    // see here for details: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html    
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this method, but I need use change event. 

In addition, this problem exists only in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to use the keypress event, not the change one.